# Sending a message between 2 objects

Tags: c++, oop

I have objects A and B that need to send and receive messages from each other.

For example:

I click, this causes A to send a message to B. B does something with it then sends A another message as a reply.

Right now the way I have it is,
A has a B* and B has an A* and they call each other's sendMessageTo method to communicate.

Is there a better way to do this sort of thing?

Basically, the server sends a message or the local game sends a message which a polymorphic mediator takes in. The mediator either gets the message from the server or local game. The mediator passes it on to the client which does whatever with it. The idea is that the mediator should not be doing logic for the client hence message passing.

Comment: Why bother with `SendMessage`? Why not just call methods directly on the object? Is this multithreaded? Remember that everything in a single thread will be done sequentially.

Comment: B is a mediator to abstract networking (single player with bots vs multiplayer with people)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to implement Listener/Observer pattern.
from Wikipedia:

*The observer pattern (a subset of the publish/subscribe pattern) is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods. It is mainly used to implement distributed event handling systems.*

For more ref:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CppEvents.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/observer.aspx

Comment: There's also a Boost library called Boost.Signals2 which implements the Observer pattern:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/signals2.html

Signals2 allows you to attach callable listeners to a signal which you can have the Publisher of the event trigger and it will call all of the listeners.  It's a simple pattern, but Signals2 has built-in thread safety, as well as some other nifty features like aggregating the return values of the listener callables.

Comment: Check out [Active Objects](http://drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=225700095)